# Change current using PWM, for specific range outside PWM boundaries

Tags: current, atmega, potentiometer, atmega328p, digital-potentiometer

I have a circuit where I use a digital potentiometer (namely MCP41100) to change current, and I use duty between 0 and 255 (thus, I have 256 steps). The current changes from 25 micro to 50 micro. And things are running great for these numbers, but I want a different range.

What I would like to have is a current that goes between 0 and 16 milliampere with very small steps (each step is like 10 to 20 micro, thus I will have over 500 steps (16000/20)).
If you know the right component(s) to make my circuit work, please let me know. Any hint in the right direction is appreciated.

[image: Digital potentiometer simple circuit]

Comment: AFAIU, the Atmega328P has the ability to output 16 bit PWM which would give you 65536 steps, albeit at a rather low PWM frequency. You should then be able to reduce the number of steps to 500 or whatever you need by adjusting the TOP value, and gain some PWM frequency back.

Comment: Thanks, @Dampmaskin
I really should sleep. I meant that I am using a digital potentiometer to change the current. The PWM is for another part of the network. I will update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/11195c.pdf), these devices can be daisy chained.

So if you add another MCP41100 (or use a dual, MCP42100 for 100k devices) in series, you will add one effective bit, for 9 bit (512 step) resolution.

Note that the accuracy of these devices is very limited; I would probably put 4 in series for 10 bit resolution if I wanted to achieve decent precision.

There are [quad devices](http://www.analog.com/en/products/digital-to-analog-converters/digital-potentiometers.html) available, incidentally.